# Happens-Before relation in volatile fields

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In Java Concurrency In Practice, it says that

> A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of
>   that same field

Does that mean if **two threads try to simultaneously read and write to a volatile field**, the **JVM will ensure that the write operation precedes the read operation** or would there be a race condition anyway ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *happens-before* relationship has an extremely specific meaning in the Java specification. Oracle provides an overview of what it means [in their concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

It's important to understand that the relationship is defined over time spent on the CPU. In other words, it has nothing to do with the initial order in which events occur: a write or a read could come first in your application.

It rather says that **if** the write is executed first, **then** the effects of that write will be visible to all threads before they execute subsequent read operations. It just provides memory consistency.

Answer (score 4):

There would be a race condition. The outcome would depend on who gets there first:

- If the write is first, the happens-before guarantees that the read will see the new value.
- If the read is first, the happens-before with the most recent earlier write guarantees that the read will see the value of that write.

Answer (score 2):

If the write to the volatile field happens before the read of that field, then volatile will guarantee that the read will be the **latest** value.

**Note volatile does not guarantee atomicity, it guarantees visibility.**